# Incorrect rounding issues, round down instead of up

Tags: php

I have a points system in place, at the moment, a customer gets assigned points and for every 500 points they get awarded a £5 voucher.

At the moment this is what I have, if someone is on 900 points then the output is showing that they have earned £10 so far which is incorrect. How can I round down so it'll just show £5 then when they get over 1000 points it'll show £10 etc.

```
  <?php if($total >= 500) {
    $voucher_count = $total / 500;
    $voucher_rounded = round($voucher_count, 0) . "<br />";
    $voucher_total = $voucher_rounded * 5; ?>
    <p class="earnings-to-date">You've earned £<?php echo $voucher_total; ?> so far</p>
  <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the modulo operator (`%`) to filter out the extra 400 (or whatever it is) before dividing by 500:

```
$total = 900;

if($total >= 500) {
    $voucher_count = ($total - $total % 500) / 500;
    $voucher_total = $voucher_count * 5;
    echo $voucher_total;
}
```

Output:

```
5
```

The modulo operator calculates the *remainder* of a division by the specified number.  In this case:

```
($total - $total % 500) / 500;
```

Works out the remainder (`$total % 500 = 400`), subtracts it from `$total` and then divides by `500`.

Answer (score 2):

floor — Round fractions down
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

```php
$total = 900;

if($total >= 500) {
    $voucher_count = $total / 500;
    $voucher_rounded = floor($voucher_count);
    $voucher_total = $voucher_rounded * 5; 
    echo $voucher_total; // Output: 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `floor`:

```
$voucher_total = round(floor($total/500)) * 5;
```